# How to run class activity in jar file in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I'm new in Android, I've had some problems

I have 2 package:

1. fr.keuse.rightsalert.activity
2. com.example.process

I export the first package into jar file a and then I add to the second package as library. I do like this:

1. I copy the jar file to /libs in the second package
2. I add to build path

the second package import like this:

```
import fr.keuse.rightsalert.activity.ApplistActivity;
```

and here is the problem code when I call class in jar file (throwing a `Nullpoiterexception`

```
private OnItemClickListener listlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView parent, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clicked on" + position +((Order)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getOrderName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         //------------show new intent when clicked-----------------    
        switch (position){
            case 0:     
                **new fr.keuse.rightsalert.activity.ApplistActivity();
                Intent i = new Intent(System_app.this,ApplistActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);**
                break;

            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clicked on number 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }   
    }
};
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace from your logcat

Comment: What is this line: "**new fr.keuse.rightsalert.activity.ApplistActivity();"? Don't instantiate activity objects. Android does this for you when you call `startActivity()`

Comment: new fr.keuse.rightsalert.activity.ApplistActivity(); I just create new class belong to the first package, I think so but it doesn't work. Can you help me, please

Comment: @DavidWasser: here is my logcat </br> 02-28 07:54:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 07:54:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.process/fr.keuse.rightsalert.activity.ApplistActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 07:54:54.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1961)

Comment: This can't be the whole stack trace. It should tell you on what line and in what method the NullPointerException occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
new fr.keuse.rightsalert.activity.ApplistActivity();
```

You don't instantiate activities like this. All you need to do to start an activity is this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(System_app.this,ApplistActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Android will instantiate the activity for you.

Make sure that you have **not** defined a constructor for `ApplistActivity`. Make sure that you have a method `onCreate()` in `ApplistActivity`. Make sure that you have this activity listed in your AndroidManifest.xml.